# Is password filtered when sending params with curl?

Tags: curl

How secure is it, when you sending username and password with cURL --form or --data option? Compare to the browser form submitting, what's the difference between them?

For example, how is the following different to a browser form?

curl --from username=fred --form password=secret http://example.com

Comment: There is a typo in your command (from* should be form). Browser send lots of headers, cookies and request is natural to web server. Where as, you need to add many param i  curl to make it look like same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl emulates a browser, so over the network they're both the same, HTTP being insecure and HTTPS being mostly secure. The browser adds some extra headers that `curl` may not send by default, but it can be made to do so.

The problem with sending it using `curl` using that command is more local, if you're unlucky and someone runs `ps` (or the task manager) at the wrong moment, may see your command line, including the password.

Comment: Hi Joachim, thanks for your answer. I'm currently building an API for people to upload files from third party application, but I need to authenticate them with username and password. For the long run I will buy a certificate, but at the moment, would it be an ideal solution to send password via curl, as it's identical to the browser? If someone sniffing in the middle, would the password be visible to him? If it's insecure, dose that mean any website using HTTP login is also insecure?

Comment: @FredXinFan Yes, basically, any web site where you log in over HTTP is insecure to someone sniffing your traffic (for example if you're at an Internet Café). The same goes for Curl, since it uses HTTP too. HTTPS certificates are pretty cheap, the price shouldn't be stopping you from making it secure.

Comment: Thanks so much for your confident answer, Joachim. That was helpful. Sorry about so many questions, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Curl is using HTTP just like your browser. It is just as secure/insecure as sending a username and password with the browser. (Over HTTP, insecure, and over HTTPS, secure enough for most purposes.)

Now, there are subtleties. For example, if you are on a multiuser system, someone else may be able to look at the process table to see your password in plain text while you are running the command.

And it's possible that curl may not be as aggressive in warning you about SSL peculiarities (certificate wonkiness, weaker keys than you might like, etc.).  I honestly don't know how much of a fuss curl makes in those situations.

But broadly and very generally speaking, it's identical to the browser.